# SQL Statement - Too dumb to figure it out

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a working knowledge of SQL Server along with the ability to perform most basic queries. However, I'm stuck and needs some help with this one. I have 6 related tables from which I need to derive a set of data.

Tables are as follows:

`MTMeterReadings` mr

- Actual
- GroupID
- MeterID
- CreateDate

`MTMeterReadingGroups` mg

- MeterReadingGroupID
- MeterSourceID
- EquipmentID

`MTMeterSources` ms

- MeterSourceID
- Description

`MTMeters` m

- MeterID
- Description

`SCEquipment` eq

- EquipmentID
- CustomerID

`ARCustomers` c

- CustomerID
- CustomerName

My desired result set is to show the following data for each Actual record in the MTMeterReadins table where mr.CreateDate > 'mm/dd/yyy':

```
mr.actual | mr.CreateDate | ms.description | e.EquipmentID | c.CustomerName
```

So far, I've been able to create a query with everything I need except `c.CustomerName`, but just can't seem to take it all the way (I can be JOIN challenged at times).

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

---

I apologize, but I didn't know if the query I already had would be helpful or not.

Here is what I have that yields everything I want except customer name:

```
SELECT   
   mg.EquipmentID, 
   CAST(mr.Actual AS decimal(12, 0)) AS Meter, 
   CAST(mr.CreateDate AS DATE) AS MeterDate, 
   ms.MeterSource, m.Description
FROM     
   MTMeterReadings AS mr 
INNER JOIN
   MTMeterReadingGroups AS mg ON mr.MeterReadingGroupID = mg.MeterReadingGroupID 
INNER JOIN
   MTMeterSources AS ms ON mg.MeterSourceID = ms.MeterSourceID 
INNER JOIN
   MTMeters AS m ON mr.MeterID = m.MeterID
WHERE    
   (mr.CreateDate >= '01/01/2014') AND (mr.CreateDate <= '02/20/2015')
ORDER BY 
   MeterDate DESC, mg.EquipmentID, m.Description
```

However, every attempt that I have made to add `CustomerName` yields a multiple of the records that I have in the `mr` table. I can't tell exactly what my error is, but I'm assuming it is an incorrect join. Maybe simple for someone with a bigger SQL brain than me, but this is far from being inside my core knowledge base as I learned SQL from a SAMS "Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes" book.

Comment: So are you going to show us what you have so far?

Comment: If you have the first four fields, it seems its just one more join from SCEquipment to ARCustomers using the CustomerID fields.  Is there some other complication involved?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing additional 2 joins:

```
SELECT   mg.EquipmentID, CAST(mr.Actual AS decimal(12, 0)) AS Meter, CAST(mr.CreateDate AS DATE) AS MeterDate, ms.MeterSource, m.Description, ar.CustomerName
FROM     MTMeterReadings AS mr INNER JOIN
            MTMeterReadingGroups AS mg ON mr.MeterReadingGroupID = mg.MeterReadingGroupID INNER JOIN
            MTMeterSources AS ms ON mg.MeterSourceID = ms.MeterSourceID INNER JOIN
            MTMeters AS m ON mr.MeterID = m.MeterID
INNER JOIN SCEquipment eq on mg.EquipmentID = eq.EquipmentID
INNER JOIN ARCustomers ar on eq.CustomerID = ar.CustomerID
WHERE    (mr.CreateDate >= '01/01/2014') AND (mr.CreateDate <= '02/20/2015')
ORDER BY MeterDate DESC, mg.EquipmentID, m.Description
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as this:

```
SELECT mg.EquipmentID,
    CAST(mr.Actual AS DECIMAL(12, 0)) AS Meter,
    CAST(mr.CreateDate AS DATE) AS MeterDate,
    ms.MeterSource,
    m.Description
    c.CustomerName
FROM MTMeterReadings     AS mr INNER JOIN 
    MTMeterReadingGroups AS mg ON mr.MeterReadingGroupID = mg.MeterReadingGroupID INNER JOIN 
    MTMeterSources       AS ms ON mg.MeterSourceID = ms.MeterSourceID INNER JOIN 
    MTMeters             AS m  ON mr.MeterID = m.MeterID INNER JOIN 
    SCEquipment          AS e  ON mg.EquipmentID = e.EquipmentID INNER JOIN 
    ARCustomers          AS c  ON e.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE (mr.CreateDate BETWEEN '01/01/2014' AND '02/20/2015')
ORDER BY MeterDate DESC,
    mg.EquipmentID,
    m.Description
```

But that's assuming that there are no possible outer joins and that every relation you want has at least one record.

Also, note that if `mr.CreateDate` is a `datetime` you will miss times on 2/20/2015 after midnight.

Comment: AhhHahh! Outside of a couple of typos on my part for table names, you nailed it. Thank you. On the date comment, are you saying that "between" is inclusive or exclusive of the two dates?  . . . Actually, through trial-and-error I see that it is inclusive of the start date but exclusive of the end date.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ChrisZumwalt No, between is *always inclusive*,  The query I wrote is logically identical to your query (typos aside).  The problem is that `'02/20/2015'` translates to a datetime of `'02/20/2015 00:00:00'`.  If you want everything between 01/01/2014 and 2/20/2015 and the field has time in it, you have to say `mr.CreateDate >= '01/01/2014' AND mr.CreateDate < '02/21/2015'`.  That's "after midnight on or after Jan 1, but before midnight on Feb 21".  Basically: Remember that midnight is as the start of a day!